# Matrix multiplication Big O notation

Tags: java, big-o, computer-science

I have a question regarding best case scenario for this piece of code and worst case scenario in Big O notation. From my point of view, it should be O (n^3) for both cases but some people disagree.

```
public int [][] multiply (int [][] A, int 
 [][] B, int n) {   
int [][] C = new int[n][n]; - 1 ( ignored )
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {        - n 
  for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {  - n 
     if(A[i][j ]!=0) {  - 1 ( ignored )
         for (int k=0; k<n; k++) {   - n
              C[i][k] += A[i][j]*B[j][k]; - 
        }
      }
     }
   }
 return C;
```

}

Comment: If `A` is all zeros, it should be O(n^2).

Comment: *Best* case is that all values in `A` is zero. So _O(n^2)_. Average and Worst case are both _O(n^3)_.

Comment: turned @Andreas answer into a community wiki answer

Answer (score 1):

It is true that matrix multiplication takes O(n^3) time to run in average and worst cases. For 2 matrices of dimensions m x n and n x p respectively, there is going to be a total of m*n*p (or n^3 for simplicity) calculations, one for each entry in the resultant matrix. As for the best case, it depends on what your program does when it sees that at least one of the matrices is a zero matrix (all entries in the matrix are 0). If it can spot a zero matrix, then you can short circuit the program. In this case, the running time is going to be O(n^2) (you just scan a couple of n x n matrices at most), which is the best that can be achieved for matrix multiplication. If this optimization is not available, the program will run in O(n^3) in any case. Either way, you can still say that the best case is O(n^3) because of the definition of Big-O notation, but that is not of interest to most people.

Comment: *"It is true that matrix multiplication takes O(n^3) time"* - you mean the simple matrix multiplication algorithm - matrix multiplication itself is a problem, not an algorithm, and there are other algorithms which do it in less than cubic time.

Answer (score 0):

The line of code shown above must be corrected.

```
C[i][k] += A[i][j]*B[j][k];
```

It should be corrected as follows.

```
C[i][j] += A[i][k]*B[k][j];
```